# Regex that expresses "at least one non-digit"

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to validate usernames according to this schema:

1. Allowable characters: letters, numbers, hyphen, underscore
2. First character must be a letter or a number
3. The username cannot be all numbers

This regular expression satisfies 1 and 2 above, but I can't figure out how to satisfy 3:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d][\w\-]+$/
```

(I'm using Ruby, if that's relevant)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not very efficient, but simple:

`/^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z\d][\w\-]+$/`

The lookahead simply means: "what follows isn't a string of numbers that go on until the end".

Comment: neat trick, is it available in non-ruby regex implementations?

Comment: +1 Nice one. I usually avoid lookahead's because I don't grasp them very well, but this is a nice illustration of how to use them.

Comment: @Mark: Not in all, but in the most. Python, PHP, Perl and Javascript are ones I know support it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can go with two passes, a simpler and faster second pass regexp is:

```
/[^\d]/
```

This just matches anything that is not a number and it needs to match only one and it terminates early. You don't really need to be strict here because the first pass already rejects non-allowable characters.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but easy: Use a second pass with the regex `/^.*[a-zA-Z_\-].*$/`

Just ensure it passes both and you'll be fine.

Comment: `/\D/` would do just as well if you run a second filter. There's no need to match from start to end.

Comment: The second pass can just be `[-a-z_]` (I assume you're doing a case-insensitive match; if not, then `[-A-Za-z_]`, of course. No need to worry about beginning, end or anything else -- if it passes the first one, just make sure there's a letter, underscore, or hyphen anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about Ruby, but Java only reports a match if the entire string matches. I assume \D is not digit?

Comment: @David: Yup, non-digit. As for matching, most engines (including Java) provide a `match()` and `search()`/`find()` methods. The former tries to match the whole string, while the latter tries to match at any point.

Comment: This is why I love SO, I learn something new and useful everyday.

Comment: Actually, if we're talking 2 passes, the first pass should be /^\d+$/. It would negate the need for a second pass if the uname is all digits. An aside /^(\d|\-)$/ might be better

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regex that you need for validation and then something like:

```
passwd.to_i.to_s.length != passwd.length
```

to verify that `passwd` is not a string of digits after it passes the primary validation.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way, though it may not perform as well as Max's:

```
/^[a-z0-9][-\w]*[-_a-z][-\w]*$/i
```